# Recyclerview with viewpager with fragments in which again Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to implement RecyclerView - in which every cardview get contains viewpager with fragments.inside that every fragment there is another ListView OR RecyclerView.

I implemented but it can't load data after 3rd recycler item on view.

See below image like this I want to implement:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While implementing this design you will face some dynamic height issues so that time use this viewpager https://github.com/iffa/wrapping-viewpager

Comment: is this UI possible in android to implemet or not? @mdg5435

Comment: Yes it is possible. Why would i given you above comment.

Comment: OK thanx but in my viewpager m adding fragments with dyanamic data. and want also to get the every card items slected tab position status.

Comment: thanx for help.. @mdg5435

Comment: I have tried to implement this UI, scrolling vertically is working fine but while swiping viewpager of recyclerview item, some part of it freezes.

Comment: I think, i will not recommend to use multiple viewpager with fragments in the recyclerview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135376/discussion-between-prashant-and-mdg5435).